# Are the RLS filter and Kalman filter gradient methods?

Tags: kalman-filters, adaptive-filters, adaptive-algorithms, gradient

I would like to extend my previous question
[What is difference between LMS and gradient-descent adaptation?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30605/what-is-difference-between-lms-and-gradient-descent-adaptation)
with this other question.

I found out, that RLS and Kalman filter learning seems to be somehow similar. My question is: Can be those algorithms called gradient descent methods? If not, how is this kind of algorithms called?

Comment: Recursive least squares (RLS) filters don't use gradient descent. As their name suggests, they use a least-squares fit to determine the optimum coefficients at each time step. Via clever formulation of the filter structure, one can use the calculations done from time step $n$ to recursively calculate the updated coefficients for time step $n+1$ without having to do the full least-squares fit again.

Comment: @JasonR Good to know. Does this approach a common name? Can you create an answer from your comment please?

Comment: Done. I'm not sure what you mean about the name of the approach; it's recursive least squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive least squares (RLS) filters don't use gradient descent. As their name suggests, they use a least-squares fit to determine the optimum coefficients at each time step. Via clever formulation of the filter structure, one can use the calculations done from time step $n$ to recursively calculate the updated coefficients for time step $n+1$ without having to do the full least-squares fit again.

Comment: well, the least square solution actually nullify the gradient at each step.

Comment: //Via clever formulation of the filter structure,// You mean the lattice structure?

Comment: Actually, this is far from optimal. And the $\lambda$ dependence turns it a parametric algorithm, such any standard gradient procedure.